# How to get custom field values from quote table in observer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, email-templates, custom-field

I have added a custom field in checkout form and saved that values in quote table. And also displayed in the backend in order details. Now I want to send that custom field value in email.
I have used observer to do so. When static value is passed then it is printed in email but I am not getting any solution to get the custom field value from quote table and pass it in email.
I am getting order id but from that order id please help/guide me to find the custom field value.

Below is my code

```
namespace Rishi\Emails\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddMyData implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $order=$transport['order'];
        $orderId=$order->getEntityId();

        $transport['myvar'] = $orderId;
        $transport['payment_html'] = 'myvar';
    }
}
```

I have created a custom template and added {{var myvar|raw}}.

Please help me.

Comment: What event are you usign for the observer ?

Comment: 'sales_model_service_quote_submit_before' this event.@Taschert

Answer (score 1):

> You have to save that quote value to the order table and then get
> direct value in an email template.
>
> 1. For save quote value to order table. Define Events in the events.xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="save_custom_fee" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddCustomField" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> 2. Now Create an Observer file to Handle Logic once trigger an action for the event

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
/**
 * Save Custom Field in sales_order before place an order.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCustomField implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this;
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        // Get Order Object
        /* @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        // Get Quote Object
        /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $event->getQuote();

        if ($quote->getCustomField()) {
            $order->setCustomField($quote->getCustomField());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> 3. Write in order email template   {{var order.getCustomField()}}

Comment: I am already saving that value in order table. Is there a way to get value from 'quote' table?

Comment: Please check this link if it helps. [link for email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335632/how-to-display-product-name-in-the-subject-of-the-emailorder-confirmation-email/335642#335642)