# How to display Product Name in the subject of the Email(Order Confirmation Email)?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, email-templates, order-email

I want to display product name in the subject of the Order confirmation email.
I want to display like this
**Your Order for LooMantha Refrigerator... has been successfully placed**

Comment: What if order contains more than one products?

Comment: @Rahul Barot it has to show only first product and dots(.....)

Comment: @Rahul Barot it has to show only first product dots(.....) and n(number of remainig products) more products has been successfully placed

Comment: Okay, let me check if i can find something helpful to you.

Comment: is any solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. First, you need to create “events.xml” file inside your extension folder. app\code\Mital\EmailSubjectItems\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="order-add-custom-field-data" instance="Mital\EmailSubjectItems\Observer\Emailtemplatevars"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

2. After that, you need to create “Emailtemplatevars.php” file using below code inside that file. In this file, you can add one or more parameters.
   app\code\Mital\EmailSubjectItems\Observer\Emailtemplatevars.php

   ```
    <?php
        namespace Mital\EmailSubjectItems\Observer;

        class Emailtemplatevars implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
        {
            protected $helper;        
            public function __construct(           
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order  
            )
            { 
                $this->order = $order;
            }


            public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
            {       

                $transport = $observer->getTransport();
                $orderId = $observer->getTransport()->getOrder()->getId();
                $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
                $totalItems = count($order->getAllVisibleItems());
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
                {
                   if($i == 0){
                     $productName = $item->getName();
                     break;
                   }
                    $i++; 
                }

                if($totalItems > 1){
                    $more = $totalItems - 1;
                    $transport['itemName'] = $productName.'..and '.$more .' more products'; 
                }else{
                    $transport['itemName'] = $productName .'product';   
                }

            }
        }
   ```

   ?>

> 3. and add below code inside that file. app\design\frontend\Themes\Yourtheme\Magento_Sales\email\order_new.html

```
<!--@subject Your Order For {{var itemName}} has been successfully placed @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"
} @-->
 
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
 
<!-- add your all custom parameter -->
 
<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
               
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>.' store_email=$store_email |raw}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(1) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                      {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your custom data in transport data object, for that you can use below observer

> app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="change_new_order_email_subject" instance="Vendor\Moule\Observer\AddCustomData"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In observer write code to add your custom variable to template

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AddCustomData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class AddCustomData implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $order;        
    
    public function __construct(           
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order  
    )
    { 
        $this->order = $order;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $orderId = $observer->getTransport()->getOrderId();
        $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
        $allVisibleItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $totalItemsCount = count($order->getAllVisibleItems());
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($allVisibleItems as $item)
        {
            if($i == 0){
                $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if($totalItemsCount > 1){
            $remainingItems = $totalItemsCount - 1;
            $transport['itemName'] = $productName.' and '.$remainingItems .' more products'; 
        }else{
            $transport['itemName'] = $productName;   
        }
    }
}
```

Now in order to use this parameter in email subject you need to override default order email template in your custom theme

> app\design\frontend\YourVendor\your_theme\Magento_Sales\email\order_new.html

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Your Order For "}} {{var itemName}} {{trans "has been successfully placed"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.shipping_description":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message",
"var created_at_formatted":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var store.frontend_name":"Store Frontend Name",
"var store_phone":"Store Phone",
"var store_email":"Store Email",
"var store_hours":"Store Hours",
"var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1])":"Customer Account URL",
"var order_data.is_not_virtual":"Order Type",
"var order":"Order",
"var order_id": "Order DB Id",
"var order_data.customer_name":"Customer Name"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.frontend_name}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$created_at_formatted |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order_data.email_customer_note}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```